# how do i paginate my query in Athena using Lambda and Boto3

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-api-gateway, amazon-athena

I am querying my data in Athena from lambda using Boto3.
My result is json format.
when I run my lambda function I get the whole record.
Now how can I paginate this data.
I only want to get fewer data per page and
send that small dataset to the UI to display.

Here is my Python code:

```py
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    athena = boto3.client('athena')
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    query = event['query']
    # Execution  
    query_id = athena.start_query_execution(
        QueryString=query,
        QueryExecutionContext={'Database': DATABASE},
        ResultConfiguration = {'OutputLocation': output}
    )['QueryExecutionId']
```

I use postman to pass my query to get data and
I am aware of the SQl query LIMIT and OFFSET
but want to know if there is any other better way to pass LIMIT and OFFSET parameter in my function.
Please help me in this case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search and found this answer in the Athena docs, which seems to be promising. [Example from the docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/athena.html#Athena.Paginator.GetQueryResults.paginate)

```
response_iterator = paginator.paginate(
QueryExecutionId='string',
PaginationConfig={
    'MaxItems': 123,
    'PageSize': 123,
    'StartingToken': 'string'
})
```

I hope this helps!